# Artisan Command - Foreach Laravel - Contar linhas afetadas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Criei um command no Laravel para executar em um determinado horário e agora eu preciso obter o resultado somente das linhas afetadas.
O método que utilizei faz uma contagem de todo o loop.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
if (empty($contact->nome))
continue;
if (empty($contact->cnpj))
continue;

$contato = $company->clientes()->updateOrCreate([
'cpf_cnpj'          => $contact->cnpj
], [
 'cpf_cnpj'          => $contact->cnpj,
 'company_id'        => $company->id,
 'nome'              => $contact->nome,
 'fantasia'          => $contact->fantasia,
 'tipo'              => $contact->tipo,
 'ie_rg'             => $contact->ie_rg,
 'endereco'          => $contact->endereco,
 'numero'            => $contact->numero,
 'bairro'            => $contact->bairro,
 'cep'               => $contact->cep,
 'cidade'            => $contact->cidade,
 'complemento'       => $contact->complemento,
 'uf'                => $contact->uf,
 'fone_cell'         => $contact->fone,
 'email'             => $contact->email,
 'limiteCredito'     => $contact->limiteCredito,
 'situacao'          => $contact->situacao,
 'contribuinte'      => $contact->contribuinte,
 'dataNascimento'    => isset($contact->dataNascimento[0]) ? $contact->dataNascimento : null
]);
 $count++;
 $contato->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas se você quiser saber quais campos foram alterados na variavel `$contato` (no caso do resultado do `updateOrCreate` for uma edição, na criaão ele não vai funcionar), basta usar o `getChanges()`:

```php
$contato->getChanges();
# ['bairro' => 'Nome do bairro alterado']
```

Caso queira saber realmente a linha no arquivo que foi alterado... Eu não acho uma boa prática, porque se for adicionado mais campos, você vai ter que se preocupar em mapear o atributo com a linha.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que o resultado do `update` ou `create` vai gerar um objeto do `ORM` na variável 
`$contato`, neste caso pode ser possível utilizar o método `count()` no mesmo:

```
$contato->count();
```